# Fluids as a special case of fields

Tags: fluid-dynamics, field-theory

Can we consider fluids as fields like Higgs EM fields?
I have doubt about the equation of motion of fields and fluids.

Comment: Fluids exhibit viscous behavior, which is dissipative.

Comment: One often describes fluid flows as having [*velocity field*](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Classical_Mechanics_(Dourmashkin)/28:_Fluid_Dynamics/28.02:_Velocity_Vector_Field), so seems you might want to clarify how you mean "field"

Comment: @KyleKanos field as in function of space and time like temperature , electric field

Comment: @quanity if your definition of "field" is just a function over spacetime, then yes, hydrodynamics is a field theory. Generally speaking, the dynamics of fields is ruled by partial differential equations (in contrast, the dynamics of particles, or bodies with a limited number of degrees of freedom, by ordinary differential equations).

Comment: @quanity Velocity fields *are* functions of space & time, so I'm not sure what you're using to distinguish that from temperature or electric fields.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit vague, but there is a relationship between hydrodynamics and electrodynamics. In superfluids, where there is no resistive flow, its **velocity** field can mimic the electromagnetic field.

Suppose a body travels through a fluid with a velocity $u$. For an ideal, irrotational vortex-free fluid, there are a few conditions:

- Incompressibility: $\oint_{\partial S} \vec v (\vec r, t) \cdot \text{d}\vec S = 0$ for a closed surface $\partial S$.
- Irrotational: $\oint \vec v(\vec r, t) d \vec r = 0$ for a closed path.
- Boundary of body: $\vec v (\vec r, t)\cdot \hat n = 0$ at the surface of a body.
- Boundary at infinity: $\vec v (\vec r, t) = -u \hat x$ as $|\vec r| \to \infty$.

These would be the exact same conditions for body with permittivity $\varepsilon = 0$ placed in an electric field $\vec E = -E_x \hat x$. The only difference here is that there will be an electric field that is inside the body, while the fluid is only outside.

For a superconductor though, the Meissner effect predicts that the magnetic field expels its inside field, so there will be a one-to-one relation.

With this analogy, you can see many similarities. For example, the pressure felt by a fluid will be $\rho v^2/2$ which is analogous to the energy density of the magnetic field $B^2/2\mu_0$ with some differences in physical constants.

This relationship is very useful to do many things. For example, for a fluid there is a quantity called the added mass because the motion of kinetic fluid will add to extra energy to the body. You can first go to the superconductor analogy, derive a formula and then replace it with the hydrodynamic version.